# Mule FTP: how to move up one directory?

Tags: ftp, mule

I need to configure a FTP inbound endpoint in Mule, what I got so far is this:

```
<ftp:connector name="ftpConnector" pollingFrequency="1000"
     validateConnections="true"
     moveToDirectory="C:\Users\jonbrynjar.FRETT\Documents\national_registry"
     moveToPattern="*.txt"/>
<ftp:inbound-endpoint host="ftp1.xxxx.is" port="21"
     user="xxxx" password="xxxx" binary="false"
     pollingFrequency="5000" responseTimeout="10000"
     connector-ref="ftpConnector">
  <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="../einst.txt" />
</ftp:inbound-endpoint>
```

I can access this server in command prompt this way:

```
user:xxxx
pass:xxx
cd ..
get K0274K.N4503.EIN.E32 einst.txt
get K0274K.N301.F300 fyrirt.txt
bye
```

I think the problem is I am not able to move up one directory as implied in the command text!

How would I implement this action Mule?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the mule's composite source to use multiple source(The path of the folder being different in each ) .

```
<flow name="MuleRunnerFlow1" doc:name="MuleRunnerFlow1">

<composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">

<ftp:inbound-endpoint host="ftp1.xxxx.is" port="21" user="xxxx" password="xxxx" binary="false" pollingFrequency="5000" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="ftpConnector" doc:name="FTP" path="/parent">
<file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="einst.txt" />
</ftp:inbound-endpoint>

<ftp:inbound-endpoint host="ftp1.xxxx.is" port="21" user="xxxx" password="xxxx" binary="false" pollingFrequency="5000" responseTimeout="10000" connector-ref="ftpConnector2" doc:name="FTP" path="/parent/children">
<file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="einst.txt" />
</ftp:inbound-endpoint>

</composite-source>

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />

</flow>
```

You May use two connectors or same connector based on your requirement and you can take the path and other properties from the property file if necessary

Hope this helps